# Как разлогиниться в Stackoverflow?

Tags: поддержка, аутентификация, интерфейс

Создал профиль, используя ВКонтакте. Теперь не могу разлогиниться.

Comment: на быструю руку не нашел...но как вариант удалить куки с ссайта > обновить страничку

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Получается, это единственный способ.